# sorting an array and counting its elements

Tags: java

I tried to sort an array accending and count the array elements
please help me find whats missing, have debugged many times. here is my code and the output i got. Thanks

```
package habeeb;

import java.util.*;

public class Habeeb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[30];
        int i, count=0;

        System.out.println("Enter the integers between 1 and 100" );

        for( i=0; i<num.length; i++){
            num[i]= input.nextInt();
            if(num[i]==0)
                break;
            count++;
        }
```

calling the function here

```
        Sorting(num, i, count);
    }

    public static void Sorting(int[] sort, int a, int con){
        if (a<0) return;
 /*am sorting the array here*/
        Arrays.sort(sort); 
        int j, count=0;

        for(j=0; j<con; j++){
            if(sort[a]==sort[j])
                count++;
        }

        System.out.println(sort[a]+" occurs "+count+" times"); 
        Sorting(sort, a-1, con);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
run:
Enter the integers between 1 and 100
2
5
4
8
1
6
0
0 occurs 6 times
0 occurs 6 times
0 occurs 6 times
0 occurs 6 times
0 occurs 6 times
0 occurs 6 times
0 occurs 6 times
```

Comment: Please reindent, put brackets (even for a single if) and count them too.

Comment: You want to count the number of occurrence of digits in a given array...yes?

Comment: yes, and do it should be in an acceding manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

The counting method

```
public int count(int[] values, int value)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int current : values)
    {
        if (current == value)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Then use

```
int[] sorted = Arrays.sort(num);
for (int value : sorted)
{
    System.out.println("" + value + " occurs " + count(sorted, value) + " times");
}
```

This works for sure.

Comment: Hmm interesting site, however you still don't need to sort.

Comment: and thanks to@Woot4Moo, i will research on your solution.....thanks for the enlightenment

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the array is of size 30 and when you sort it you have all the values you did not assign to equal to 0 and thus they go in the front of the sorted array. Later on out of the first 6 numbers all are 0 so the output you have is correct.

To aviod the problem you face I suggest you use `ArrayList` instead of simple array so that you can add elements dynamically to it.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a bit more work than is necessary.  I would solve this like so:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();  


for( i=0; i<num.length; i++){
    int current = input.nextInt();  
    if(countMap.get(current) != null)  
    {  
        int incrementMe = countMap.get(current);  
        countMap.put(current,++incrementMe);  
    }  
     else  
     {  
         countMap.put(input.nextInt(),1);  
     }  
}
```

Comment: This is pretty clearly homework for someone in highschool or firstyear. They are probably limited to native arrays. Way too many people here just always jump right into collections. People have to learn to implement their own sorts as well so they can learn the basics. You don't even try to explain why to use a Map. -1

Comment: @Lucas and yet other people in the "real world" do this exact same thing, where they end up doing way too many operations to solve a trivial problem.  If you read my post you would have noticed that I explicitly called out OP was doing too much work.  If you would like I can give the theta complexities as to why it is more correct to use the Map, but than again that does seem like a bit of overkill for such a trivial problem no?